# Totalizar produtos através de duas tabelas - Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, inner-join

Desejo que o resultado da SELECT retorne:

> nome.produto | Crédito | Débito | Saldo
>   Crachá 076   |10  |     5  |  5
>   Crachá 064   |     20  |    10  | 10

Tabela: produtos [produto.id / produto.nome]
Tabela: crachas [crachas.id / id_produto ]
Tabela: creditos [id_cracha / credito]
Tabela: debitos [id_cracha / debito ]

No SELECT que montei apenas uma totalização deu certo a outra repetiu a soma de todos o produtos encontrado na tabela.

```
SELECT produtos.nome, (SELECT SUM(creditos.credito) FROM creditos) AS 'Crédito', (SELECT SUM(debitos.debito) FROM debitos) AS 'Débito' FROM produtos 
INNER JOIN crachas ON crachas.id_produto = produtos.id
INNER JOIN creditos ON creditos.id_cracha = crachas_id
INNER JOIN debitos ON debitos.id_cracha = crachas_id
GROUP BY produtos.id;
```

Banco: MySql
Outra coisa, pode haver valores NULOS.
Agradeço qualquer ajudar.

Comment: Não foi dito o SGBD , pesquise por PIVOT CASE IIF exemplo à rodo.

Comment: O banco é Mysql

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/saldo-de-debito-e-credito-no-mesmo-registro-mysql/597158

Answer (score 0):

Opa, boa noite!
Pelo sua explicação creio que seja isso.

```
 SELECT produtos.nome
       , SUM(creditos.credito) as 'Crédito'
       , SUM(debitos.debito) as 'Débito' 
FROM produtos 
INNER JOIN crachas 
    ON crachas.id_produto = produtos.id
INNER JOIN creditos 
    ON creditos.id_cracha = crachas_id
INNER JOIN debitos 
    ON debitos.id_cracha = crachas_id
GROUP BY produtos.nome;
```

Minhas modificações foram retirando  (SELECT SUM... e deixando somente o SAM para ambos os campos.
Também modifiquei a coluna do group by colocando a coluna do select.